# ActiveMQ Classic 6 on Docker - When login to Admin console with default credentials I get 401 unauthorized error

Tags: docker, activemq-classic, docker-desktop, unauthorized

I am using the `latest` official ActiveMQ Classic 6 [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/activemq-classic/tags) via Docker Desktop. However, authorization doesn't work with default credentials (i.e. `admin`/`admin`). I am getting 401 unauthorized error. Does anyone know why?

I tried the same with ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.3, and I managed to authorize with default credentials.

[image]

Successful authorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solutions it to use correct `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS`. Here is example for `docker compose`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  amq:
    image: apache/activemq-classic:6.0.1
    environment:
      - ACTIVEMQ_OPTS= -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/apache-activemq/conf/login.config
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
```

tl;dr;

Looks like, due to web interface not being accessible by default in docker, they added `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS= -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0` as default environment variable in docker. This prevents `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS` to be set to same value as if would be empty (like usual local installation).

```
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config"
fi
```